# Change color of Pattern overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I wonder if its possible to change the color of a pattern overlay in Photoshop?

I googled a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

So I have a layer with pattern overlay, but I also want to use color overlay so I can set a color for the pattern.

Thanks

Comment: This should give you what you want:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/photoshop-multiple-overlay-effects/4274#4274

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes You can do this,

set the color overlay blend mode to `Color`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and what about gradient overlay, set it to "color" also? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you took to much time to respond! anyways what exactly you want to do? if you are having gradient overlay selected make sure color is not selected, and set it to like "multipyl or overlay"

Comment: @Nimbuz this one can help you : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/photoshop-multiple-overlay-effects/4274#4274