# Is there any way of applying a gradient overlay over a color overlay in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

Whenever I add a color overlay layer style to an object in photoshop, it goes over top of any gradient overlay I have. Is there any way to change this order?

Comment: You also might want to take a look at this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/photoshop-multiple-overlay-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to change the order, but there is a workaround.

1. Set the layer with the color overly.
2. Duplicate the layer [layer 2] so it's above the first layer [layer 1]
3. Set the Fill for Layer 2 to 0%
4. Apply the Gradient Overlay to Layer 2.

Comment: thanks.. that'll do it. i've used the fill 0 trick for outlines before.. a bit irritating to have to do that but all ya can do is all ya can do ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or You could try this method:

1. Set colour overlay on the layer
2. Transform the layer to a smart object
3. Set the gradient effect of the smart object

This way You have both effects on the same layer and You can also edit them.